# i want select value of select tag by id of json

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

i send data of items by json to select tag by this json:

```
function GetItems() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/NewOrder/GetItems/",
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {

            var s = '<option value="-1">Select</option>';
            for (var m = 0; m < result.length; m++) {
                s += '<option value="' + result[m].ID + '">' + result[m].ItemName + '</option>';
            }
            $("#ItemsID").html(s);
            $(".ItemsIDMDL").html(s);
        },
        error: function (errormessage) {
            alert(errormessage.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

than i get data of order details from json by this code :

```
function getbyID(Id) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/NewOrder/GetOrderByID/" + Id,
        contentType: "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            GetItems();
            var rows = '';
            $.each(result, function (key, item) {
                rows += '<tr id="trr">';
                rows += '<td>' + item.code + '</td>';
                rows += '<td> <select name="Items" class="ItemsIDMDL form-control" id="ItemsIDMDL' + item.id + '"></select></td>';
                $("#ItemsIDMDL"+  item.id).val(item.id);
                $("#select_id").val("val2").change();
                rows += '<td> <select name="Sizes" class="form-control"></select></td>';
                rows += '<td>' + item.Quantity + '</td>';
                rows += '<td>' + item.Price + '</td>';
                rows += '<td>' + item.Total + '</td>';
                rows += '</tr>';
                
            });
            $('.orderdetailsmodel').html(rows);
            //$('#ItemsIDMDL'+ item.id).val(item.id).change();
            
            $('#myModal').modal('show');
            $('#btnUpdate').show();
            $('#btnAdd').hide();
            $('#myModal').modal('show');
            $('#btnUpdate').show();
            $('#btnAdd').hide();
            //})
        },
        error:
            function (errormessage) {
                alert(errormessage.responseText);
            }
    });
    
}
```

the problem is that i want to make selected value is the id of item
so i wrote this code :

```
  $("#ItemsIDMDL"+  item.id).val(item.id);
```

but it did not work

please help me

Comment: You're trying to select the element before you add it to the DOM with `$('.orderdetailsmodel').html(rows);`. Also, there are no options in the `<select>`, so how can you set its value?

Comment: how can i select the element after adding it to the DOM?

Comment: Put the loop that sets the values after you do `$('.orderdetailsmodel').html(rows);`

Comment: But it won't work if the select doesn't have any options.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to set the value of an element before you add it to the DOM. Move that code to a second loop that runs after `$('.orderdetailsmodel').html(rows);`.

But I'm not sure how you expect this to work. The value of a `<select>` has to be the value of one of its `<option>`s. But you didn't put any options in the `<select>`.

```js
function getbyID(Id) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/NewOrder/GetOrderByID/" + Id,
    contentType: "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(result) {
      GetItems();
      var rows = '';
      $.each(result, function(key, item) {
        rows += '<tr id="trr">';
        rows += '<td>' + item.code + '</td>';
        rows += '<td> <select name="Items" class="ItemsIDMDL form-control" id="ItemsIDMDL' + item.id + '"></select></td>';
        rows += '<td> <select name="Sizes" class="form-control"></select></td>';
        rows += '<td>' + item.Quantity + '</td>';
        rows += '<td>' + item.Price + '</td>';
        rows += '<td>' + item.Total + '</td>';
        rows += '</tr>';
      });
      $('.orderdetailsmodel').html(rows);
      $.each(result, function(key, item) {
        $("#ItemsIDMDL" + item.id).val(item.id);
      });
      $("#select_id").val("val2").change();

      $('#myModal').modal('show');
      $('#btnUpdate').show();
      $('#btnAdd').hide();
      $('#myModal').modal('show');
      $('#btnUpdate').show();
      $('#btnAdd').hide();
      //})
    },
    error: function(errormessage) {
      alert(errormessage.responseText);
    }
  });

}
```

Comment: i get the option by function called : GetItems();

Answer (score 0):

i get the option by function called : GetItems();

i wrote the code by this way :

```
function getbyID(Id) {
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/NewOrder/GetOrderByID/" + Id,
    contentType: "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result) {
        GetItems();
        var rows = '';
        $.each(result, function (key, item) {
            rows += '<tr id="trr">';
            rows += '<td>' + item.code + '</td>';
            rows += '<td> <select name="Items" class="ItemsIDMDL form-control" id="ItemsMDL' + item.ID + 'ID"></select></td>';
           // $('#ItemsMDL' + item.ID + 'ID').find(item.ItemName).val();
            console.log("select")
            console.log("#ItemsIDMDL" + item.ID);
            $("#select_id").val("val2").change();
            rows += '<td> <select name="Sizes" class="form-control"></select></td>';
            rows += '<td>' + item.Quantity + '</td>';
            rows += '<td>' + item.Price + '</td>';
            rows += '<td>' + item.Total + '</td>';
            rows += '</tr>';
            
        });
        $('.orderdetailsmodel').html(rows);
        //$('#ItemsIDMDL'+ item.ItemName).val(item.ItemName).change();
        $.each(result, function (key, item) {
            console.log("item")
            $('#ItemsMDL' + item.ID + 'ID').find(item.ItemName).val();
            console.log("#ItemsIDMDL" + item.ItemName);
        });

        $('#myModal').modal('show');
       
        $('#btnUpdate').show();
        $('#btnAdd').hide();
        //$.each(result, function (key, item) {

        //$('#id').val(result.ID);
        //$('#ClientNamePU').val(result.RealName);
        //$('#RegionPU').val(result.Region);
        //$('#GovernoratePU').val(result.GovernorateName);
        //$('#CallStatuPUID').val(result.CallStatuName).change();
        //code = OD.item.code,
        //              ItemName = OD.item.ItemName,
        //              size = OD.size.SizeName,
        //              Quantity = OD.Quantity,
        //              Price = OD.Price,
        //              Total = OD.Total
        //})
    },
    error:
        function (errormessage) {
            alert(errormessage.responseText);
        }
});
```

}

but it isn't work too